# retrieve locations using location's distance in android studio

Tags: android

I want to get locations by providing distance from person's own place. I have already taken locations through android google map and inserted the locations in the database. now I want to retrieve those locations from the database by providing location distance.

Comment: Please share your code. And add more detail to your requirement.

Comment: Please show what you have done. It is impossible to suggest improvements without seeing your current solution.